# Python - create CSV file

Tags: python

I am using the code below to create a file using Python. I don't get any error message when I run it but at the same time no file gets created

```
df_csv = pd.read_csv (r'X:\Google Drive\Personal_encrypted\Training\Ex_Files_Python_Excel\Exercise Files\names.csv', header=None)

df_csv.to_csv = (r"C:\temp\modified_names.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `df_csv.to_csv` to a tuple, which is not how you call methods in python.

Solution:

```py
df_csv.to_csv(r"C:\temp\modified_names.csv")
```

`DataFrame.to_csv` documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Edit: I also noticed the title says "Create Excel File"

To do that you would do the following:

```py
df_csv.to_excel(r"C:\temp\modified_names.xlsx")
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually make the .csv file like this:

```
import csv
with open(FILENAME, 'w') as file:
 csv_write = csv.writer(file,delimiter='\t')
 csv_write.writerow(LINE)
```

LINE : is an array of row you want to write